# Change numbers to seconds in R

Tags: r, time

I have numbers looking like this: 3038, 2180, 2120 etc. and what they really mean is for e.g. 3038 = 3 minutes, 3 seconds and 8 tenths. I have over 100 000 observations in this column.
What I want is only seconds:
183,8 seconds

Should I use lubridate for this and how?

Comment: Do you mean 183.8 (8 tenths) or 183.08 (8 hundreds)?

Comment: Yes sorry I meant tenths so 183.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer using mathematical operations to convert numbers. Maybe this helps:

```
onlysecs <- function(x) (x/1000-floor(x/1000))*100
minsecs <- function(x) floor(x/1000)*60
onlysecs(x) + minsecs(x)
#[1] 183.8 138.0 132.0
```

**data**

```
x <- c(3038, 2180, 2120)
```

Hat tip to @docendo discimus for pointing out that `sapply()`is not required.

Comment: Nice solution, I'd just put both in one function, i.e. `f <- function(x) (x/1000-floor(x/1000))*100 + floor(x/1000)*60` and since it's vectorized you don't even need any `sapply` call: `x <- c(3038, 2180, 2120); f(x)`

Comment: Thank you but how do I apply that to the column with the 118 000 observations? :)

Comment: Yes, of course - this can be converted to a one-liner. I sometimes find it clearer to separate functions.

Comment: @Cham  You see the `x`? Replace it by the column.

Comment: Thank you! I'm quite new with R...  :)

Comment: I typed in this:
f <- function(Pop1$Race.time) (Pop1$Race.time/1000-floor(Pop1$Race.time/1000))*100 + floor(Pop1$Race.time/1000)*60

And I got this...
Error: unexpected '$' in "f <- function(Pop1$"

Comment: @Cham, don't use `Pop1$Race.time` in your function definition. Instead, use any variable, like "x", type `f <- function(x) (x/1000-floor(x/1000))*100 + floor(x/1000)*60` and then run `f(Pop1$Race.time)`

Comment: The class is numeric

Comment: I could easily solve this problem in Excel but I'm not allowed to =P
Is it easier if it's possible to split the column so I have the minutes in one column and so on??

Comment: I think it's better and faster to do this in R. Can you post a small portion of your data? Like `dput(head(Pop1,5))`.

Comment: Okay now it worked when I created a new data frame with every number >0 but how do I get these numbers in a new column at the correct places. I mean these numbers are for individuals with "ID".

Comment: WOHO I managed to get a new column with these numbers =D thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
num <- c(3038, 2180, 2120)
m <- regmatches(num, regexec("(\\d)(\\d{2})(\\d)", as.character(num)))
sapply(m, function(x) { 
  x <- as.integer(x) * c(0, 60, 1, 1/10)
  return(sum(x))
})
# [1] 183.8 138.0 132.0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `substr`

```
as.numeric(substr(t1,1,1))*60 + 
      as.numeric(substr(t1,2,3)) + 
      as.numeric(substr(t1,4,4))/10
#[1] 183.8 138.00 132.00   NA
```

Or with `strsplit`

```
i1 <- t1!=0
t1[i1] <- t(sapply(strsplit(gsub('(.)(..)(.)', '\\1,\\2,\\3', t1[i1]),
         ','), as.numeric)) %*% c(60, 1, 1/10)
t1
#[1] 183.8 138.0 132.0   0.0
```

#### data

```
t1 <- c(3038, 2180, 2120, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you but I forogt to mention that I have about 118 000 observations ;) where some of the values are 0...

Comment: @Cham In my first solution, the 0 elements will give NA and in the second solution, we may need to exclude those 0 elements.

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution:

```
n<-c(3038, 2180, 2120) 
minute<-as.integer(n/1000)*60
lastdigit<-n%%10/10
mid<-as.integer(substr(as.character(n),2,3))
sum<-minute+lastdigit+mid
sum 

[1] 183.8 138.0 132.0
```